# Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.kerberosutil in windows cmd.exe

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, mkdir

**Q: When I trying to create a directory using this command "hadoop fs -mkdir /input_dir" in cmd.exe after successful Hadoop installation. I am getting this error. I will attach the screenshot, below.**

C:\hadoop-2.10.0\sbin>hdfs dfs -mkdir /sample WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication. util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/hadoop-2.10.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2. 10.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance() WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop. security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release mkdir: Call From LGNNV1CC to localhost:9870 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information"

[http://i.imgur.com/a/Uh4Spx5](https://i.imgur.com/a/Uh4Spx5)